# Calculating the coordinates of a line vertical and centered to another given line

Tags: math, coordinates, trigonometry

I have the following things given:

x-Coordinate of the first line: 0
y-Coordinate of the first line: 0
angle of the first line : 135deg
length of the first line: 10

offset to second line: 5

First, I have to calculate the x2 and y2 coordinates of the first line, which I did as following:

```
var x2 = length * Math.cos(Math.PI * angle / 180.0);
var y2 = length * Math.sin(Math.PI * angle / 180.0);
```

Now I have (x1|y1) and (x2|y2) given. Based on that, and the offset given I need to calculate the coordinates of a line vertical to the first line with the same length as the first line. What Im trying to achieve is the following picture, the yellow line is what is given and green whats needed.

[image]

I do know that I have to use sinus and cosinus, however I couldnt manage to get a formula that works with every given angle. If anyone could provide a formula or guide me in the right direction, I would be very grateful. Thanks in advance

Comment: This answer is useful
0

What I understand you need (x3,y3) and (x4,y4). You would require the intercept co-ordinate of the yellow line and the green line also. If you need the lines the way you have drawn it. Otherwise the actual line segment could be anywhere, as long as it has the appropriate angle.

Comment: Well, the intersection point of the yellow and the green line can be calculated pretty easily: `var xIntersection = (offset+length) * Math.cos(Math.PI * angle / 180.0);``var yIntersection = (offset+length) * Math.sin(Math.PI * angle / 180.0);`

Comment: No, use tan. Triangle = (x1,y1)-(a,b)-(x4,y4). Angle (x3,y3),(x4,y4),(x1,y1) = 180-90-(135-90)=45 (isosceles right angled triangle). Line (x4,y4)-(a,b)=10+5=15 (since tan 45 is 1). Both the lines are of same size!? How is that possible, unless I am missing something in the problem.

Comment: I really cant understand how you get to 15

Comment: Name the points, (x1,y1)=a, (x2,y2)=b, (x4,y4)=c, (x3,y3)=d. If line ab is extended, let it intersect line dc at (a,b)=e. Line ab has an angle of 135 to vertical. Triangle aec is a right angled triangle. Angle aec is the right angle. Angle cae=135-90=45, therefore angle ace=180-90-45=45. Therefore triangle aec is an isosceles right angled triangle. Therefore its base=its height (tan 45 = 1 = perpendicular/base). If height = 5+10=15, ec is also 15. Now in your problem does line ce extend till projection of ab or falls short. The 1st case will not be possible as ab=10 and ec=15. 2nd case possibl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure this is the fastest implementation
but I think it's easy to follow and can be a test for a faster routine:

the steps are:

1. bring the line to the origin
2. rotate 90 degrees
3. return to original location
4. add the "offset" (and half the length)

the full computation is:

1. find the center of the line `[a, b] = [(x1 + x2)/2, (y1 + y2)/2]` and subtract it from both ends. you get `[x'1, y'1] = [x1 - a, y1 - b]` and `[x'2, y'2]` similarly
2. use the [2D rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix), for 90 degrees it's simply `[[0, 1], [-1, 0]] * [x'1, y'1]`
3. add back `[a, b]` to both points
4. (mark the angle with `theta` and distance with `d`): add `[(a + d)*cos(theta), (b + d)*sin(theta)]` to get to the final position